# REGEX to extract data from slightly different strings in VB.NET

Tags: regex, vb.net

I've got the following three strings that I need to extract some data from

```
randomData1§randomData2§randomData3
randomData1§randomData2§randomData3
randomData§randomData§randomData1§randomData2§randomData3
```

I need an expression that would work with all three of the above strings to give:

```
(randomData1) (randomData2) (randomData3)
(randomData1) (randomData2) (randomData3)
(randomData§randomData§randomData1) (randomData2) (randomData3)
```

randomData2 and randomData3 will always be numbers (ex: `10`, `100`, `1045`, etc) and always be separated by `§`. Anything towards the left of `§randomData2§` can hugely vary might also contain the delimiter `§`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can 'anchor' a regex matching pattern to the end of the subject string using the '$' char as a last char of the pattern. So try something like this:

```
^(.+)§([^§]+)§([^§]+)$
```

Note that I have no idea about VB, this is plain regex usage. I assume VB uses some standard regex engine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply arkascha but this expression gives me 4 captures: `randomData§randomData§randomData1§randomData2§randomData3 & 
randomData§randomData§randomData1 & 
randomData2 & 
randomData3` the last three captures are exactly what I want but not the first. Is there any way to get the last three only?

Comment: I meant to apply the pattern to single lines of the subject. If you want to apply it to the whole subject, then you have to deal with the linebreaks too inside the pattern. I think you can figure that out yourself, now that you have a starting point. It helps understanding regexes, which is important to anyone trying to learn to program :-)

Comment: It is a single line, tired it on `randomData1§randomData2§randomData3` and I get 4 captures instead of just 3, one of which is the string itself.

Comment: http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/9412/regextest.jpg the last three elements are perfectly enough but the first is just repeating the source string itself. Any way to capture the needed data only? Thanks man

Comment: Ah, sorry, now I get your problem. Ok: as said I have no idea of VB, but in other langauges regex functions always return result sets holding a first entry with the total matched string. It is not always the originial subject, just the matched part. You can simply unshift() it from the result array since it is always present. Note that this is a question of your VB function(), not the regex I gave matching four tokens. And I _stongly_ suggest that you read the manual of the regex function you use. That first return element certainly is clearly explained in there...